# Dynamics CRM 2013 rich text editor

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am using Dynamics CRM 2013.

How does one apply the rich text editor styling seen on the description field on the email form to other multiple line text fields? Viewing the source code it is obvious that the system is treating the rich text field very differently from the normal multiple line text fields in that instead of rendering a textarea it is rendering a table with an embedded iframe.

In CRM 2011, I have used extensions that wrap up the TinyMCE editor but they were never very effective. It seems odd that I can't just check a box to do this to any text field in the settings when the behaviour is obviously built in.

Thanks in advance.

Richard.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not supported in CRM by default. If you need it you have to customize CRM. However it is not so difficult, if you follow my tutorial here:
[Rich Text Editor (WYSIWYG) in CRM 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28476052/2066007)

The thing is that you will create one web resource html page which you can then reuse on different entity forms by simply adding iframe linking to this web resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a backing field in an entity in which you need an editor and thereafter utilise that field alongside a webresource that generates HTML for you. For instance, the webresource could be an HTML file that includes a Javascript file, the latter providing the functionality of the Rich Text Editor functionality. One of the most popular Rich Text Editor for the web is [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/). I Implemented this idea using TinyMCE and have posted the code and the CRM solutions (managed and unmanaged) on [Codeplex](https://xrmtinymce.codeplex.com/).

Furthermore, this solution works on both CRM 2013 and CRM 2015