# Using ckeditor in CRM 2013

Tags: ckeditor, richtextbox, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to use the ckeditor to add a rich text field on a form on a custom entity in my CRM 2013 on premises instance (see original instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476051/rich-text-editor-wysiwyg-in-crm-2013?answertab=active#tab-top)). I have added ckeditor as a managed solution to my CRM instance, added the new Web Resource, and added both an iFrame and a Web Resource to my form (I added both to see if one way worked and the other did not).

I am able to see the WYSIWYG toolbar at the top of the field; however, my text is not being saved. I have defined a Custom Parameter in my Web Resource holding the HTML code. Also, I noticed my Audit History is now being stopped when I click save on the record.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something very similar in the past, and also ran into some issues. Are you seeing any errors when opening the F12 debugger in your browser? You could add a debugger statement in the editor script to step through the code to see why it is breaking. Example:

```
// Get the target field name from query string
debugger;
var fieldName = getTextFieldName();
var Xrm = parent.Xrm;

var data = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldName).getValue();
document.getElementById('editor1').value = data;
```

Comment: This would be the correct approach to figure out what's going on (in using the browser debugger to step through the code).  If you aren't seeing the audit data, it means that some sort of JavaScript error is preventing the data changes from being saved.  I ran into this myself trying out this type of a solution and after stepping through the code and figuring out what I had made a mistake in, I was able to have the HTML editor save the data to the CRM field.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Make sure the parameter matches the field you have created that stores the HTML generated by the editor. Check out the documentation for xrmtinymce [here](https://xrmtinymce.codeplex.com/) on how this is done.

As to your second concern about Audit History, so long as you have enabled auditing on the entity and you are saving HTML into one of the fields in the entity your Audit History functionality shouldn't be affected.